# I cannot do loadMore in relay even there are more items?

Tags: reactjs, relayjs, graphql-js

I have read from https://github.com/facebook/relay/blob/master/packages/react-relay/modern/ReactRelayPaginationContainer.js and https://facebook.github.io/relay/docs/pagination-container.html

My count variable is working and I think I have set it up correctly but I cannot loadMore items and my hasMore is false which means I have no more todos to display.This is my code:

```
export default createPaginationContainer(TodoList,
  {
    viewer: graphql`
            fragment TodoList_viewer on User {
              todos(
                first: $count  # 
              ) @connection(key: "TodoList_todos") {
                edges {
                  node {
                    id,
                    complete,
                    ...Todo_todo,
                  },
                },
              },
              id,
              totalCount,
              completedCount,
              ...Todo_viewer,
            }
        `,
  },
  {
    direction: 'forward',
    getConnectionFromProps(props) {
      console.log("getConnectionFromProps props ",props)
      return props.viewer && props.viewer.todos;
    },
    getFragmentVariables(prevVars, totalCount) {
      console.log("getFragmentVariables total count ",totalCount )
      return {
        ...prevVars,
        count: totalCount, // the total of displayed todos on the fragment
      };
    },
    getVariables(props, {count}, fragmentVariables) {
      console.log("getVariables count ",count)
      return {
        count,
        // cursor,
        // in most cases, for variables other than connection filters like
        // `first`, `after`, etc. you may want to use the previous values.
        // orderBy: fragmentVariables.orderBy,
      };
    },
    query: graphql`
      query TodoListPaginationQuery( # assign component name + Pagination + Query
        $count: Int!
      ) {
        viewer {
          # You could reference the fragment defined previously.
          ...TodoList_viewer
        }
      }
    `
  });
```

I don't know what I am doing wrong here. Maybe if you know a working sample for this(which I cannot find in github) I would really appreciate

Answer (score 0):

Is your server exposing the pageInfo of the connection correctly?. The `TodoConnection` type should have the following fields

1. `edges: [TodoEdge]`
2. `pageInfo: PageInfo!`

The `PageInfo` type should have the following fields:

```
endCursor: String
When paginating forwards, the cursor to continue.

hasNextPage: Boolean!
When paginating forwards, are there more items?

hasPreviousPage: Boolean!
When paginating backwards, are there more items?

startCursor: String
When paginating backwards, the cursor to continue.
```

I couldn't find an example either but I suggest you take a look at those types/fields. If you have GraphiQL installed in your stack then you could also try querying manually to discard any server related problems.

Comment: I explecitly added it all in pageInfo, hasNextPage is true but but this.props.relay.hasMore() returns false

Answer (score 0):

What version of React-Relay are you using? Can you try using 1.5.0, I am facing the same issue, but I can't upgrade 1.5.0 as of now.

I think 1.5.0 release might fix this problem:
https://github.com/facebook/relay/releases/tag/v1.5.0

Fix commits:

- Fix end cursor when fetch returned zero edges in Pagination Container
- Fix pagination on empty connections